# Print out a tuple where each character of the alphabet is repeated as many times as its position

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tuples

I want to print the tuple `('a','bb','ccc','dddd'....)` that ends with 26 copies of the letter `'z'`.

I am using a `for` loop to print.
But I have to make a list first then convert it into the tuple.
Can I make it directly into a tuple?

Here's my code:

```
l = list()
c = 1
for a in range(97, 123):
    l.append(chr(a)*c)    
    c = c+1
print(l)
t = tuple(l)
print(t)
```

Comment: Could you make it work with one of the answers?

Answer (score 1):

You can build the tuple directly by using the `tuple` constructor and a generator comprehension.

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> offset = ord('a') - 1
>>> print(tuple(c*(ord(c) - offset) for c in ascii_lowercase))
('a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd', 'eeeee', 'ffffff', 'ggggggg', 'hhhhhhhh', 'iiiiiiiii', 'jjjjjjjjjj', 'kkkkkkkkkkk', 'llllllllllll', 'mmmmmmmmmmmmm', 'nnnnnnnnnnnnnn', 'ooooooooooooooo', 'pppppppppppppppp', 'qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq', 'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr', 'sssssssssssssssssss', 'tttttttttttttttttttt', 'uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu', 'vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv', 'wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy', 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz')
```

Unfortunately, you cannot build a result-tuple by appending sub-solutions to it, because tuples are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

```
e = ()
for s in range(97, 123):
  e = e + (s, )
print(e)
```